# Disabling "Ubuntu Desktop Guide" Dialog

Tags: 16.04, unity, shortcut-keys, settings, system-settings

Since quite a while, I keep accidentally popping up the "Ubuntu Desktop Guide" dialog, I have already searched for an application to remove, but the only thing I found was gnome-user-guide, which was the wrong thing. Also, I searched for shortcuts in the settings of Ubuntu.

One of the situations where it pops up is, when I change from console to UI mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (Number).

How can I delete the shortcut or delete the whole dialog?

Comment: If you have an icon in the launcher that's a blue question mark then right click on > Unlock from Launcher

Comment: No, i didn't pin the help application to my launcher.